# calculating the MFCC and BFCC for a signal

Tags: matlab

I'm wondering, is there any function in Matlab to extract the Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (MFCC) and Bark Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (BFCC) from a signal?

Here is an example of my data:

[image: raw data]